# RSA Decryption Produces Wrong Result

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa

I am trying to implement RSA encryption and whenever the decryption part is implemented, I get the wrong answer.

Everything up until encryption gives me the correct values: n is 187, phi is 160, e is 3, private key d is 107 and the cipher-text c is 183. Afterwards, I compute c^d first (which gives me -9223372036854775808) then do mod(n) on that result to get -162 (supposed decryption).

I presume that the error is in the c^d portion but I cannot put my finger on what is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    long p = 11;
    long q = 17;
    long n = p * q;

    double phi = (p-1) * (q-1);
    int e = 3;

    while(e < phi) {
        if(GCD(e, phi) == 1) break; //GCD is a function that returns the GCD
        else e++;
    }

    int k = 2;
    // private key computation
    double d = (1+(k*phi))/e;

    double msg = 72;

    long c = pow(msg, e);
    // c mod(n)
    c %= n;

    long decr = pow(c, d); 
    decr %= n;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use GMP, RSA is not mean to use small modulus. Also, the common way is to choose e than select the primes.

Comment: When you say choose e then select primes, is my approach above different? I select e then choose the closest coprime.

Comment: `e` is usually chosen as Fermat Primes so that it contains fewer bits in order to decrease the computation. Though, this is another story since enables power attacks. You select the primes than e

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to compute the modulus (`O(n)` complexity)

```
//Compute a^b mod n
int powermod(int a, int b, int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i=1;i<=b;++i) {
       result *= (a%n);
       result %= n;
    }
    return result%n;
}
```

You can modify fast power in similar way to compute mod of exponent. It uses the following formula

```
a^b mod n = (a mod n)^b mod n
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wonder where int b is used in the function?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I corrected the code. `b` is the exponent.